# cannot access data property of undefined when retrieving facebook comments

Tags: javascript, facebook, console, undefined

My issue seems to be retrieving comments from the users feed from facebook. It gets the type and the message properties just fine. So I can use them within the control structure to output what I want. However, the comments property is acting strange. The console seems to throw the error cannot access data property of undefined. So I added another if statement testing for comments. I have tried adding undefined and null, but if I get `feed[item].comments` I just get undefined even if I log the current `feed[item]` to the console and the comments are there.

//I stripped this code down as most of it will just get in the way
//so up here is my success function for the ajax call and is also where 'resp' comes from...

```
var feed = resp['feed'];

for(item in feed) {

    switch(feed[item].type) {

        case "status":

            if(feed[item].message === undefined || feed[item].message === null) {

                //console.log(feed[item].comments);

                if(feed[item].comments !== undefined) {

                    console.log(feed[item].comments.data.length);

                }

            }else if(feed[item].story === undefined || feed[item].story === null) {

                //console.log(feed[item].comments);

                if(feed[item].comments !== undefined) {

                    console.log(feed[item].comments.data.length);

                }

            }

            break;

    }

}
```

Suggestions are appreciated :)

Comment: We need more details: What api endpoint are you calling? Are you sure it has the message property? Do you have a JSfiddle for this? In other words, can we see your code?

Comment: It does have the message property, but I will probably have to create a stripped down working version of it on jsfiddle.

Comment: Actually I don't think I will able to get jsfiddle up as I would expose information that would be private to my facebook account in order for it to work.

Comment: Ok, tell me the API endpoint, and give me more code(apart from the personal information).

Comment: Sorry just figured out my issue it was partly due what you suggested. However, when I stripped down the code I forgot to include the else if where feed[item].story === undefined. I also had to make sure to test for feed[item].comments !== undefined so it wouldn't get to the point where it can throw the error

Comment: Please edit the code: the if-else part seems to do the same as the if part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64882/discussion-between-aravind-and-user3832583).